# The inaccurate targetcontentoffset of the Scrollview proxy method is an IOS bug？

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a textview, in which I set more than 10000+ lines of content

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textView.delegate = self;
    
    NSMutableString *mustr = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        [mustr appendFormat:@"%i\n",i];
    }
    self.textView.text = mustr;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{
    NSLog(@"Get expected stop position:Get expected stop position%f",willEndPoint.y);
}
```

I set a button. After stopping, I click the button to print the true offset value of textview

```
- (IBAction)TESTBTN:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Final roll stop position:%f",self.textView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

I found that the more you slide, the greater the deviation between the expected position and the implementation position. Does anyone know what's going on? Is it an interface bug

Comment: What is willEndPoint ?

Comment: It means where he will stop in the future